# AttributeError: module 'django.core.serializers' has no attribute 'ModelSerializer'

Tags: django, rest, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I had this error:
"`AttributeError: module 'django.core.serializers' has no attribute 'ModelSerializer'`" before running makemigrations[image: my import statements][image: the supposed error code][image: settings.py][image: the error message]

Though I have imported serializers from rest_framework, and I have added rest_framework to my installed app, it still did not work

Comment: Try not to put code as images

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it, the problem was Django was using the serializers imported from the django.core package instead of using rest_framework, which I specified.
To fix the problem, I had to override that by giving it an alias, then using the alias instead. [image] If you have an easier solution, please share